# Embedding dates in SQL queries in R using sprintf

Tags: r, sql-server

I have dataframe, called df which I am pulling into R via the following code:

The values of column 1 are 1,2,3,4 and 5. I want to reference the values of this DataFrame in a SQL query in R.

I do the following:

vals<-Data$'Column1'

I embed the query in R via the following

```
df2 <- dbGetQuery(database,sprintf("

SELECT      column1,
            column 2 
 FROM database 
 WHERE value IN (%s)",toString(vals)))
```

However, I would like to make this query a function of date and pull in data only after a certain date. Let's call the date column date_col. The natural thing to do would be

```
query_function<-function(date){

df3 <- dbGetQuery(database,sprintf("
    
    SELECT      column1,
                column 2 
     FROM database 
     WHERE value IN (%s)
     AND date_col>=%s,toString(vals),toString(date)))

}
```

When I do this, it doesn't pull in data only after my specified date. If I put date='2021-01-01', I'm seeing data from as far back as 2005!

Any help would be appreciated.

I am also open to solutions using the paste function if you prefer.

Comment: Does R use JDBC? You could pass a [Table Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). Another option is to create a temp table and load it using `dbWriteTable`. Or you could pass in JSON or XML and shred it with `OPENJSON()` or `.nodes()` respectively. Not familiar with R enough to help you do any of these

Comment: No, R is not JVM-based.

Answer (score 0):

> If I put date='2021-01-01', I'm seeing data from as far back as 2005!

Probably because your query becomes

```
SELECT      column1,
            column 2 
 FROM database 
 WHERE value IN (%s)
 AND date_col>=2021-01-01
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT      column1,
            column 2 
 FROM database 
 WHERE value IN (%s)
 AND date_col>=2019
```

and unfortunately SQL Server allows comparison of 'datetime' to 'int', and the current date converted to int is `44564`, which is larger than `2019`.

So use parameters, if R supports it, or pass the value as a string, not a math expression.  eg

```
SELECT      column1,
            column 2 
 FROM database 
 WHERE value IN (%s)
 AND date_col>='%s',toString(vals),toString(date)))
```

Comment: I am passing the date as a string. That’s why it’s written like ‘2021-12-01’. I’ve even used toString(date). What you’ve said makes sense. I have no idea why it doesn’t work.